# Trouble reading data from HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpwebresponse

I have a .Net Core program that reads the contents of pages on the Internet.  I use an HttpWebRequest and have a function that reads the contents of the Results (below)

```
        private byte[] ReadFullStream(System.IO.Stream st) {
        try {
            System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(_lock);
            bool canTimeout = st.CanTimeout;
            int totalBytesRead = 0;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bool finished = false;
            while (!finished) {
                Int32 bytesRead = st.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                if (bytesRead > 0) {
                    try {
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    catch (OutOfMemoryException oome) {
                        throw new OutOfMemoryException(
                            "Failed to write " + buffer.Length +
                            " bytes to memory stream.  Memory stream already has " + ms.Length, oome);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    finished = true;
                }
            }

            var ret = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();
            return ret;
        }
        finally {
            st.Close();
            System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_lock);
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine until after up to a dozen or so pages have been read, sometimes a few as two or three, until it hangs up on the st.Read call.  It seems to freeze permanently, even when I leave it on overnight.  The st stream does not support setting the Timeout property so I cannot use that to simply abort.  I would prefer to read the page, but even if it just timed out at least the thread wouldn't hang indefinitely.  As far as I can tell, the pages generally are perfectly valid (load just fine in my browser).  I ported this code from a .Net Framework application and did not have this problem then.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a better way to read the data, or at least a way to make the Read function return if it cannot read the data?

Comment: `Read` will block on a NetworkStream until that much data becomes available. you might want to look into DataAvailable, however,  there are more succinct and elegant ways to get data from an HttpWebResponse

Comment: First thing is that when the OutOfMemoryException in your code is thrown, you are not disposing the MemoryStream, what may be cause of a leak.
If your point is just copying one stream to another, then you should take a look on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=netcore-3.1